CSS's equivalent to TeX's \phantom
Is there a CSS equivalent to TeX's \phantom command, which calculates the width of the text argument.
I would like to write something like this:
grid-template-columns: max-content width("100.00") max-content;

As a workaround I use 6ch, but I still would like to know how to get the exact value nevertheless which font-family or font-variant-numeric is used in the content.

"which calculates the width of the text argument" - where do you see the equivalent of that happen in CSS - passing of a "text argument" ...? CSS doesn't know what text it will be formatting. "but I still would like to know how to get the exact value nevertheless which font-family or font-variant-numeric is used in the content" - there is no way to do that in CSS itself. You'd have to use additional JS, that measures the dimension of the text, with all the font-relevant CSS already applied.

Could you add a runnable snippet to make clear what you are trying to achieve?

@FabrizioCalderan I am looking for something runnable, because I do not have anything runnable. I want to define the width of the column such that the text "100.00" would fit into the column.

Why wouldn't auto work?

@Paulie_D The column width should be fixed if it is empty.

You could perhaps use CSS's 'equivalent' of a phantom - a pseudo before element.
This doesn't give exactly what you require (the second column may be one character wider than you want, though if it's all numerals you could just leave off the last 0 in the psuedo element's content).
This snippet puts a transparent pseudo before element on each element in the second column with content 100.00.


<style>
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content auto max-content;
    gap: 10px;
    width: fit-content;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  .container>*:nth-child(3n+2)::before {
    position: relative;
    content: "100.0";
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2.0</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>0.0</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>12345</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>345678</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>



Note: on the browsers I've tried, the 100.00 does not get picked up by a select, but I don't know for certain whether that is true of all browsers.

Opacity 0 is a good idea.
